の浮きっぷり what does it mean?
いざ交ざるとわかる。。。若い！己の浮きっぷり!
The character is an old man and he got into a group... however after talking to everyone he realizes he's old and out of place compared to them.
Why is 浮きっぷり here used with の? I understand the character is saying he stand out and he's out of place, but whys is constructed like this? instead of 己は浮いている?

The reason why の is used here is because ～っぷり "manner of; degree of" forms a noun. 己の浮きっぷり is not really a sentence but an exclamation here, like you can simply say "O prejudice!" in English to mean you are astonished by the excess of prejudice.

いざ交ざるとわかる。。。若い！己の浮きっぷり!
You realize once you join in... [They're] young! Out-of-placeness of me!

